# Using PeriodIndex to convert dates

Tags: python, date, date-conversion

I am trying to use PeriodIndex to create quarters, days, years but recently the function stopped working for some reason. Below is a min examples:

```
 dict = [{'Date': '12/23/18'},
 {'Date': '12/24/18'},
 {'Date': '12/22/18'},
 {'Date': '12/24/18'},
 {'Date': '12/22/18'},
 {'Date': '12/24/18'}]
 df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
 df['Date2']      = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date 
 df['year']        =    pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date2'], freq='A')
```

I get this error:

```
 TypeError: Incorrect dtype
```

This used to work before but I am not sure why it does not work anymore.

Edt: I just noticed that the above commands work perfectly fine on my other computer (same version of Python, Win 10).

Comment: I figured out the problem, pandas 0.24.2 doesn't support that command, once I downgraded pandas to 0.23.4 it worked. Would still be happy to find a different solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `.values` to your date. So `df['year'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date2'].values, freq='A')` This will work!

I run into the same problem after reinstaling and upgrading Pandas. Newer versions of Pandas accept date strings that are read as a np.array using `.values` (as the author of [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26109) GitHub post also found).

Comment: What a coincidence, I just ran into this problem again today and you happened to have suggested the values approach just right now. Worked like a charm, thanks!!!

Comment: Cool coincidence, and great to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your solution works... but I needed to do this to circumvent a dtype inconsistency... so I wrote

`df['year'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['year']), freq='A')`

Comment: If someone else posts another Answer, no one will know which solution you are referencing. Kindly edit your post to either mention that your post is an addition to another Answer with a link, or keep your post independent by not mentioning another post at all, something like "I needed to do this to circumvent..." Have you taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?